# quick way to prove $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$. The number of elements and their orders are equal but I don't see a way to prove that the groups are isomorphic except for writing down the Cayley table of the group operation. Is there a better way?

Comment: Fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups?

Comment: Thanks, but I need something more elementary. So far, we only know the theorem of Lagrange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** 
What is the subgroup generated by $ (1_{\Bbb Z_2},1_{\Bbb Z_3}){}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ in $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_3$?

Comment: Ah, that's nice. This element generates a group with 6 elements which is cyclical. It seems obvious that this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$ because it has the same structure.

Comment: the isomorphism is obvious: for example $f((1_{\Bbb Z_2},1_{\Bbb Z_3})) = 1$ defines a unique morphism which is also an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, thank you!